# Weird behavior when instantiating SimpleActionClient right after initializing node in rospy

Tags: rospy, actionlib

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I ran into a problem when I ran python scripts where an actionlib
action client is intantiated right after the node a the
wait_for_server() function does not seem to work always properly (it just
does not wait).

For example:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
rospy.init_node('test_manipulation')
#rospy.sleep(1.0)

trajClient = actionlib.SimpleActionClient("r_arm_controller/joint_trajectory_action", pr2_controllers_msgs.msg.JointTrajectoryAction)

if not trajClient.wait_for_server(rospy.Duration(10.0)):
   rospy.logerr("Could not connect to actionserver " )
   exit(1)
```

will return immediately, ie. it goes into the if branch and prints the "Could not connect to actionserver " error statement, even though I would expect it
to wait 10s. If I uncomment rospy.sleep(1.0), everything works always
as expected. Is there a more elegant solution to this?

It seems like it is not always reproducable, but I have seen it on happen on my machine and the PR2 running Diamondback and Lucid.

Chris

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10290/weird-behavior-when-instantiating-simpleactionclient-right-after-initializing-node-in-rospy/) by [Chris Bersch](https://answers.ros.org/users/699/chris-bersch/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2011-06-17

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) on 2011-06-17**:
file a ticket if you can find a way to reproduce it, I just tested out your code above and things seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

file a ticket if you can find a way to reproduce it, I just tested out your code above and things seems to work fine.

---

Originally posted by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) with karma: 8372 on 2011-09-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1